# On subscription run a "callback" function once

Tags: ionic-framework, rxjs

I'm working with cordova's BLE (bluetooth low energy)

After I subscribe to notifications of BLE (which returns Observable), I want to send some message to the ble device, what is the best way to perform this, basically I need to run a function once after the subscription is made so that once device responds back to me, the code in the subscription is run.

```
ble.startNotification(deviceId, uuid1, uuid2).subscribe(bufferData=> {
   //do something with bufferData
})
```

now after this, I want to run something like a callback,

```
.then(()=> {
  //send message to device (only once), after the message is sent, the device will respond back and the `do something with bufferData` code will be run
})
```

I could easily do a `setTimeout` and send a message to the device after few seconds, and of course it works, but I want to do it cleanly, after I'm sure the subscription happened (subscription to the Observable of course)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can wrap existing method using [create operator](http://reactivex.io/documentation/operators/create.html) and add custom code that will be executed on every new subscription.

See the example:

```js
// emulate cordova with "dummy" bluetooth interface
const BLE = {
 startNotification: () => Rx.Observable.interval(1000)
}

const wrappedBLE = (...params) => 
  Rx.Observable.create(observer => {
    // constructor fn will be executed on every new subscribtion

    const disposable = BLE.startNotification(...params).subscribe(observer);

    // place code to send notification here, instead of console log
    console.log('New subscriber for BLE with params: ', params);  

    return disposable;
  });


wrappedBLE("param1", "param2", "param3")
  .subscribe(e => console.log("received notification: ", e));
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/rxjs@5.4.3/bundles/Rx.min.js"></script>
```